# How does CSS flexbox apply rules to nested divs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a tic-tac-toe board. I would think that I have to set `flex-direction: row` for each of the three divs.

However setting the css only to the outer div works: It aligns the 3 divs in a row. Why does it work?

```css
.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OUTPUT:

```
147
258
369
```

Comment: id name can be used only once, use class instead

Comment: Thx. This was just for a quick illustration. Why setting the style on the root div works correctly?

Comment: Yes styles are inherited, you will need three styles if you want total control over the layout viz. `.grid`, `.row`, `.cell`

Comment: display flex doesn't cascade down to lower levels. you need to set each container as a flex container if that's how you want it to be

Comment: Pls see updated question

Comment: Css is inherited, take a look at your devtools layouts tab, you should see some which indicated the styles being inherited

Comment: this is the regular flex behavior, since your you have numbers , you should notice the difference while using flex only on the first or only the second level, (flex-direction: row; is the default behavior,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `flex` and nested `div` to draw 3 rows of squares, you will need to size the parent and **imbricate** `flex` , with column and row `flex-direction`.

here is an example using vmin for sizing, so the `#game`, stands in the window:

```css
#game {
  height: 80vmin;
  width: 80vmin;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#game>div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  /* spray them evenly */
}

#game>div div {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
  /* spray them evenly */
  margin: 1px;
  /* or no margin */
}


/* demo, centering */

html {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}


/* add on extra flex level ? */

#game>div div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* - is vmin usefull sometines ?
- maybe */
  font-size: 8vmin;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I updated my question to make this more clear. Why does the posted HTML works just by setting the css on the root div and not in all 3 rows?

Comment: @Spiff row is the defaut behavior, to notice the difference add borders to all your divs, and notice which numbers are on the first row . flex on first level makes 1 4 7 , on the second level : 1 2 3 . It is not similar. My answer brings in the flex value and vmin size to easily draw square boxes ;) , i guess this is what you''ll need too once this first flex mystery is solved